# Calculating Profit Ratio (Gross Margin)

Tags: accounting, calculation, stock-analysis, ratio

When looking at a company's income statement to calculate the Profit Ratio (Gross Margin)

```
PM = Net Profit / Sales
```

Do you include "other" revenue in the equation?

**Example: XYZ Ltd Income Statement for 2012**

Revenues from Sales of Goods = $100

Other operating revenue = $50

Net Profit = $ 30

Should the Profit Margin ratio equation be:

```
PM = Net Profit / Revenues from Sales of Goods
PM = 30 / 100
PM = 30%
```

or

```
PM = Net profit / Revenue from Sales of Goods + Other operating revenue 
PM = 30 / (100 + 50)
PM = 20%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Understanding The Income Statement](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/04/022504.asp), it should be the former. Observe the link's sample income statement:

[image: Sample Income Statement]

The profit margin is *Net Sales* over *Net Income*. *Net Income*, meanwhile, is the sum of

- *Net Sales* (+)
- *Cost of Sales* (-)
- *Operating Expenses (SG&A)* (-)
- *Other Income (Expense)* (+/-)
- *Extraordinary Gain (Loss)* (+/-)
- *Interest Expense* (-)
- *Taxes* (-)

So you would *not* want to account for one of the above factors in addition to *Net Sales*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clarify through a description what you want, many different margin names are often used interchangeably(EBIT = Operating Income etc.)  Gross Margin the way I think you're asking  would use Gross Profit, which is Revenue - Cost of Goods Sold.  And You would arrive at Gross Margin through Gross Profit / Revenue.